# CollectionViewのカスタムセルに何も表示ができない

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

現在`ViewController`に`UICollectionView`を二つ置き、一つの`UICollectionView`はカスタムセルを使っています。カスタムセルには`UILabel`を一つ置いており、これに文字列を入れて表示させようとしているのですが、セルには何も表示されません。カスタムセルのUIを定義している`xib`ファイルの名前は「WeekPlanCell」で、`nibWithNibName`メソッドの引数と一致しています。WeekPlanCellというクラスを作り、そのヘッダファイルに`WeekPlanCell.xib`にある`UILabel`を紐付けています。そして`Storyboard`の`Collection Reusable View`の`identifier`には「afterDayCell」と入力しており、`cellForItemAtIndexPath`の`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`の引数の文字列と一致しています。
また、`Storyboard`のカスタムセルを用いた`UICollectionView`のセルの`Custom Class`のClassには「WeekPlanCell」と入力しています。
上記の手順でどこが間違っているのでしょう？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。
すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initCustomCell];
}

- (void)initCustomCell {
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"WeekPlanCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"afterDayCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 6;
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell;

    if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
        cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"todayCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell = [self.afterDayCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"afterDayCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        WeekPlanCell *weekPlanCell = (WeekPlanCell*)cell;
        weekPlanCell.layer.borderWidth = 0.4f;
        weekPlanCell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

        weekPlanCell.label.text = @"book";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UICollectionView` でカスタムセルを実装する方法は：

1. `UICollectionViewCell` をサブクラス化し、ビューのレイアウトもコードで行う
2. `UICollectionViewCell` をサブクラス化し、ビューのレイアウトは xib ファイルで行う
3. `UICollectionViewCell` をサブクラス化し、ビューのレイアウトは、Storyboard で配置した Collection View の中の、Collection View Cell を編集して行う

の 3 つになるかな、と思います。

質問文では、2 と 3 の方法を重複して使われているように見えるのですが、本来どちらの方法を使われたいのでしょうか？

---

この部分で：

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"afterDayCell"];
```

`self.afterDayCollectionView` に対して呼び出されるべきなのではないかな、と思われるカスタムセルの登録が、`self.collectionView` に対して行われています。

この場合は、Storyboard で設定した方の内容が反映される（3 の方法）と思うので、Storyboard の Collection View Cell 内で `UILabel` が配置されていなかったり、outlet の接続ができていないと、何も表示されないと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか。

2 の方法を使われる場合は、Storyboard 上のカスタムセルの設定を削除して、引用させていただいた部分のコードを修正すれば、解決できるのではないかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り[self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"afterDayCell"];をself.afterDayCollectionViewに修正するとxibで設定したセルが表示されました！nibを登録するcollectionViewが適切ではなかったのですね。誠にありがとうございました。